# Can not set placeholder for DateRangePicker::widget

Tags: php, datepicker, yii2

I have following widget in my yii2 application

```
 <?= DateRangePicker::widget([
                'model'=>$model,
                'attribute' => 'fact_close_date_range',
                'options'=>[
                    'placeholder'=>'Фактическая дата закрытия займа',
                    'class'=> 'ui input',
                    'id'=> 'fact_close_date_range'
                ],
                'useWithAddon'=>false,
                'convertFormat'=>true,
                'presetDropdown'=>false,
                'hideInput'=>false,
                'pluginOptions'=>[
                    'opens'  => 'right',
                    'locale'=>[
                        'format' => 'Y-m-d'
                    ],
                ],
            ]); 
            ?>
```

but on initial load what I am getting is input where two dates is set for today. For example 17.03.2021 - 17.03.2021, and should be my placeholder `Фактическая дата закрытия займа` like so. Documentation of kartik doesn't describe such things

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```php
<?= DateRangePicker::widget([
                                   'name'=>'date_range_2',
                                    'presetDropdown'=>true,
                                    'convertFormat'=>true,
                                    'value' => $model->date_range,
                                    // 'includeMonthsFilter'=>true,
                                    'pluginOptions'=> ['locale' => ['format' => 'Y-m-d']],
                                    'options' => ['id'=> 'tgl-search', 'class' => 'invoice-search','placeholder' => 'Select range...']
                                ]);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.